# Can I invite people to like page who liked the post when I shared into a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I usually reach people by sharing into groups. But the likes there have no effect on my page.

In my previous question I asked if we can get the likes there on my posts in the page. But that was not possible.

So now my question is if I can invite people who liked my page's post in the group to like my page.

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

If they all are in your friend list on Facebook then yes, you can [invite them to like your page](https://www.facebook.com/help/174333482624856).

If they are not in your friend list but you have their email id then yes, you can sent an [invitation to them to like your page](https://www.facebook.com/help/212291088790957/?ref=u2u)**.

If they are not in your friend list and you don't have their email id, there is not officially direct way to invite them to like your page.

What you can do is, you can post about your page with page link and ask (request) to all the group members to like your page.

<sup>**This feature isn't available to all Pages right now.</sup>